# Can I use my cousin brother's financial details as my support of finance for Schengen tourist visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, legal, schengen-visas

I am applying for a Schengen tourist visa (Germany port of entry); being a sole proprietor for the past 4 years my bank statement aren’t that good. I can bring my cousin brother into the picture to support my finances, using an Affidavit for the trip. He’s an American citizen with good financials. Will that work out?

Comment: What is a cousin brother?

Comment: @phoog it's Indian English to make the gender of the cousin clear. A male cousin.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cousin-brother

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your cousin is a resident of Germany, he might sign a formal Verpflichtungserklärung (a promise to reimburse the German state for any costs if you overstay). That will help. Otherwise, it might do more bad than good.

Germany wants to let genuine tourists in and to keep illegal immigrants out. Most genuine tourists have **clear** finances and **stable** jobs to return to. Clarity of where the money comes from is just as important as the amount.

- If your cousin gives you a loan, or merely promises to give you money if you run into trouble later, that will look bad. Many illegal immigrants pay all they own to human traffickers and go into debt.
- If you have received a gift, e.g. for a birthday, and that money is yours to spend as you like, then spending it on a holiday may be reasonable. It still won't look nearly as good as if you had earned it yourself.